# Books on Philosophy of Advaita Vedanta

Tags: vedanta, advaita

Book recommendations for a beginner to understand philosophy of Advaita Vedanta in English or English translation of works.

Comment: This is useful but it doesn't mention specific publishers .

Comment: https://www.mlbd.in/ and https://advaitaashrama.org/ also https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism and https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey

Comment: https://archive.org/details/AshtavakraGitaEnglishAudioBook several pdf and audio books on Hindu metaphysics

Comment: I'd suggest Guru Nitya Chaitanyayati's "Neither this, Nor That" (*neti-neti*). An English translation is in print.